# NameError: name 'value_from_name' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to use beautiful soup 4 to parse html for a login page and get tokens from that page.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()

login_page_html = BeautifulSoup(session.get('https://url.com',     verify=False).text)
lsd = value_from_name('something', login_page_html)


def value_from_name(name, soup):
    return soup.find(name=name)['value']
```

I got this to work in another program, but I'm not sure why it's not working here.  I'm new to python, guessing it's because I'm not passing the paramaters correctly?

Comment: What is `login_page_html`? What does _not working_ mean?

Comment: Or another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119451/call-a-function-in-python-getting-function-is-not-defined.

Comment: My bad, I accidentally had page_html = ...  instead of login_page_html, it's been fixed in the OP now.  @alecxe thanks for the link, thought I searched thoroughly for the answer and I thought in python it doesn't matter if you define the functions before or after where you call them.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the function before defining it. Define the function first, before using it.

Example -

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def value_from_name(name, soup):
    return soup.find(name=name)['value']

session = requests.Session()

page_html = BeautifulSoup(session.get('https://url.com', verify=False).text)
lsd = value_from_name('something', login_page_html)
```